# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY not working in deeplink app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've got an App that Deeplinks to another App.

Activity A is on the 1st app.
Activity B and C are on the 2nd app.

This is how the flow works:

Activity A goes to Activity B 
Activity B process some data and sends the user to Activity C

from there, everything works.

Now, when pressing the back button.

Desired behaviour:

User presses back in activity C.
The app sends the user to Activity A, skipping B entirely.

Current behaviour:

User presses back in activity C.
The app sends the user to Activity B.

What I tried so far:

Add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY from the intent that sends from Activity B to C.
Add FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP from the intent that sends from Activity B to C.

those doesn't work.

Override the onBackPressed() method in Activity C adding an intent to the deeplink App.

This works, but is not a desired solution at my workplace.

Is there another flag or I need to place it in another place?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting noHistory="true" in the manifest for Activity B?

Comment: so you want to hit back on activity C, and t should go back to the 1st application(Activity A). Instead it goes back to Actiivty B in the 2nd app?

Comment: yes, thats what I want to, but the only solution I came with is an intent overriding the onBackPressed() method with an small switch case logic because the data is sent.

Some other coworkers suggested instead of that, call finish() but it does nothing, I also looked up here, thats how I found the solution with the Intent.FLAG, doesn't work either.

My coworkers doesnt want the override logic, si I came here asking that.

If the override logic is the only way, I can use this question as backup because my expertise level (junior)